# php how to send get and post and cookie at once?

Tags: php, cookies, send

How to send get&post&cookie at once?

```
if($_GET[get] && $_POST[post] && $_COOKIE[cookie])
{
   //blah blah
}
```

How to send get,post,cookie data for that code at once??
give me a sample code please!

I used form tag but couldnt send at once but I don't know how to send it at once

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? We could just give you the code but that wouldn't much of an help...

Comment: Technically no, you cannot POST and GET at the same time. They are three different verbs. But you can realize in form by using hidden fields

Comment: "POST and GET at the same time. They are three different verbs" - 1 POST, 2 GET, 3 ...what's the third in _that_ list ;-) And `<form method="POST" action="...?a=1&b=2">` - yes, the verb is POST but `a` and `b` still end up in php's _GET.

Comment: Why would you want such a condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) - this is by default "An associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`."

Be aware that by using `$_REQUEST` you lose information about where the variable came from, so it is recommended to use the individual variables, or set `$_REQUEST` to only contain `GET` and `POST` data, with `POST` overwriting `GET`: `$_REQUEST = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);`